# Reduce time taken to compute filters in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard where I have kept all the filters used in the dashboard as global filters and most used filters I have put as `context filters`,
The problem is the time taken to compute filters is about 1-2 minutes,How can I reduce this time taken in computing these filters
I have about 2 Million of extracted data, on Oracle with Tableau 9.3

Comment: Is there any way you can restructure the workbook? I think you may be able to apply the context filtering before the actual worksheet pulls down the records -- if your filtering is done correctly, the filters get passed directly into the SQL query predicate (an actual WHERE CLAUSE and not really a 'filter') -- Try this -- Open Tableau, go to HELP > Settings and Performance > Start Performance Recording, then open your workbook and apply the filters. Once it is done loading, go to HELP > Settings and performance > Stop Performance Recording. This will give you a worksheet with the  queries used

Comment: Just to double check, you are using context filters to set filters that you don't want to change right? If you are creating an extract you can apply filters when creating the extract which I think precedes Context Filters.

Comment: Also, are you using a lot of calculated fields?

Comment: You could use a faster data source as your performance seems really slow for the volume of data. Or recognise that each filter is populated by a query (so if queries are slow then multiple filters will be *very* slow). This can be avoided by pulling the filter counters out in an extract before using them in filters to query the main data source. This might require some data restructuring for optimal speed.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Aron's point, you can also use a custom SQL to select only the dimensions and measures which you are going to use for the dashboard. I have worked on big data and it used to take around 5-7 mins to load the dashboard. Finally, ended up using custom sql and removing unnecessary filters and parameters. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you can look at it to guide performance optimization, but the details matter.

Custom SQL can help or hurt performance (more often hurt because it prevents some query optimizations). Context filters can help or hurt depending on user behavior. Extracts usually help, especially when aggregated.

An extremely good place to start is the following white paper by Alan Eldridge
http://www.tableau.com/learn/whitepapers/designing-efficient-workbooks